# Перенос ряда в горизонтальной таблице

Tags: php, html

Имеется таблица, которая отрисовывается горизонтально. Мне нужно переносить оба ряда на новую строку, если в ряде больше 7 ячеек. Есть способ это сделать?

```
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($data as $key): ?>
    <td><?= $key->date ?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<tr>

<tr>
    <?php foreach ($data as $key): ?>
        <td><?= $key->value ?></td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    if (!($i % 7) && $i)  echo '</tr><tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $data[$i] . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На выходе получается, что вначале отрисовываются две строки с датой, а ниже две строки со значениями. Нельзя сделать, чтобы они чередовались?

Comment: что у вас на входе? $data это массив или объект,  как организован?

Comment: На входе во вьюхе объект ActiveRecord. Можно выводить как массив, можно как объект, разницы большой нету. В контроллере  получаю модель по id и передаю в вид.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b61ae3d123bb65025d0d85af98333f291606445